# ANSI color codes deleting printf

Tags: c, shell, colors

Iam developing a nanoShell, for a school work, and I have a problem with ANSI color codes.

So when I run the program and I write something, and press TAB, then if I backspace my tab I can also delet my previous printf, screenshot below.

I am wondering if exists on C another way to make my printf colored, or if I can block user from pressing TAB.

After the printf, Iam using fgets to read the args introduced, by user.

```
fgets(readpos, bufSize, stdin);
```

My printf is: `printf("\033[1;31mnanoShell$ \033[0m");`

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: You may want to read about [ncurses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: @pmg I had searched for that one, because I have tryed canio.h but then I found that this library its not anymore implemented, for the users in general, so they recommend that one, but I didnt found, how to change the printfs colors.

Comment: Maybe [GNU Readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) can do what you want... I never used it.

Comment: @pmg To block, the TAB key, maybe the getchar or something! But I think its easier to change the printf color without ansi colors

Comment: Problem with Standard Library functions is that they are (usually) line-buffered, ie, you don't get the `<TAB>` or the `<BACKSPACE>` or whatever until the user types `<ENTER>` and meanwhile the position of the cursor is not under your control. There are solutions to that buffering and control (which those libraries employ) with setting device attributes or something.

Comment: @pmg Ok, I will search for it! Thanks anyways.